# How to add different versions of the same object?

Tags: java, methods, null, createprocess

I am currently trying to add a series of objects to an arrayList each time an event happens, I use the following method :

```
public void nativeMousePressed(NativeMouseEvent e) {

    if(record == true)
    {
        getInfo inf = new getInfo();
        infoCtrl info = new infoCtrl();
        info.setX(e.getX());
        info.setY(e.getY());
        infor.add(inf);


    }


}
```

The Arraylist is global, I also have a global controller and one which I make here, I tried using both. This version of the code has only the needed lines, however in the real method I test every bit with println, each time, the values are there, but after I add the object to the arrayList, everything is back to 0, just like when the object is first created.

Can anyone see the problem in this and how to fix it?

Thank you

Note : When I print the contents of the list, i get all of the objects that I added in it, but all of their values are 0, the same as like they were just created, even though before that I have a println which shows me their values perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fill the values into `info` and then add `inf` to the list.

*Hint* - The standard convention for Java is to hava all classes begin with a capital letter. That would mean you change `getInfo` to `GetInfo` and `infoCtrl` to `InfoCtrl`. Since you aren't following the convention, it makes it hard to tell how you are doing the list object (or is it a class) `infor`. (We typically find that using longer names helps keep things straight.)

Comment: Yes I do that, info is the controller of inf, where is the issue?

Comment: I guess I don't know what you mean by a controller of X and I don't see how the two objects could know about each other from the code you have supplied. There would typically be a call like `inf.setController(info)` to do that.

Comment: yes I apologize for that, to put it simply getInfo is an object in the model package, infoCtrl is it's controller and the ArrayList infor is a list of type getInfo

Comment: Ok. How does the controller know about the model or the model know about the controller. You created two new instances and no code is shown to connect them. That's all I can tell. Either you need more info in the question or you are missing something to connect these.

Comment: To put it simply I make the controller instanced, then it's constructor makes an object of type getInfo  public infoCtrl()
 {
  info = new getInfo();
 
  
 } and then it modifies all of it's values via methods such as public void setWheelDir(int wheelDir)
 {
  info.setWheelDir(wheelDir);
 }
 public int getWheelAmount()
 {
  return info.getWheelAmount();
 }

Comment: I apologize for the mess but I don't know how to do correct spacing in comments

Comment: Then you don't need to make an `getInfo` in the code you showed. You need to use the one inside the `infoCtrl` object. Or use the get and set methods to store X and Y. Then the `infoCtrl` goes in the list. Or get the `getInfo` out of the `infoCtrl` and put it in the list.

Comment: The issue was regarding a problem in the connection between the controller and the object, I fixed it now, thank you for the tips and help